# Is there a way to call myFunction() from an image, button, or link within a Google Doc, rather than using the menu?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-docs-api

I know that in Google Spreadsheets, you can bind a custom script function to the click event of an image, at least manually via the UI.

But in Google Docs, there doesn't seem to be any equivalent functionality.  The only options are timers, `onOpen()` and ilk, and creating a menu item at the top.

Am I missing a way of **adding a function launcher somewhere on the doc itself, especially dynamically from a script**?  I've searched a bunch and pored over the API docs, but I'm not seeing it.

Comment: Unfortunately, in the current stage, there are no methods for assigning function to images at Google Document yet. So as workarounds, for example, how about using Addon and the text linked to Web Apps? At Addon, you can run the function by clicking images. At the linked text, you can run the function by clicking the text. If these are not what you want, I'm sorry.

Comment: You could add a sidebar.